# Symbolization of lines on the OpenLayers map

Tags: javascript, openlayers, style, linestring

How to make a complex symbolization of the line?

I do not know what this style is called, but you need something like this:

1. broken line: [image]
2. dotted line: [image]

I can't find information anywhere on how to set such a style, although they are often found on schematic maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second use an array of two styles

```
         [
             new ol.style.Style({
                 stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                     width: 5,
                     color: 'black'
                 })
             }),
             new ol.style.Style({
                 stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({
                     width: 3,
                     color: 'white',
                     lineCap: 'butt',
                     lineDash: [9, 9]
                 })
             })
         ]
```

Comment: Thanks Mike, I didn't think it was so easy!

Comment: How to draw a (1) line here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69073845

Comment: Thank you to everyone who suggested it!